# How to successfully use time machine in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine

I just heard about time machine, it can uninstall Xcode 7.0.1 for me and give me back Xcode 6.1. How do I do this? I've had this MacBook Pro since December 2012 and i've never used time machine before. I'm not a computer guy. How can I use time machine to go back maybe 1 week at most?

Can you give me a step-by-step procedure that will work successfully for a 1 week back in time?

Comment: You can't get anything back before the time of your first TM backup like any backup. TM is just an easy to use backup system. As you are not using ut yet you need to get back Xcode 6.1 from your current backups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanics of Time Machine are pretty simple. I would recommend starting with restoring a folder with two files in it on your desktop to avoid the delays with restoring something like Xcode for your first attempt. Waiting for 5 GB or more to restore or even delete is a poor way to get feedback if you are trying to learn how to use the function.

1. Make your test data and back up manually by adding Time Machine to your menu bar.
2. After getting two backups with the folder (name it something searchable like `3821F8D0-E590-4AD5-95A3-7826E1484887` or use `uuidgen` to make a unique-ish name. Spotlight will help you locate things in Finder as well as in Time Machine
3. Delete the original folder off your desktop. (this avoids getting a prompt to replace the folder/file - so once you're ready, you'd delete /Applications/Xcode and then go to your backup to restore it)
4. Enter Time Machine and search for the folder name in spotlight.
5. Locate the time interval of your choice and select the folder
6. Click restore

It will be restored to the original location and you won't be prompted unless there is an existing version of the file/folder. Keep in mind, when you restore a folder on OS X, the behavior is almost always to delete the old folder and **everything it contains** and then replace it with the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links are useful for you.

[I have not used Time Machine before, but now need to back up to my external hard drive.  How do I do this?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4483576?start=0&tstart=0)

[**Time Machine Q&A**](http://pondini.org/TM/FAQ.html)